# How to fix UITableViewCell segue

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview, cell

I implemented a NFXRipple cell, but now the cells won't segue to the next table view. Here's my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` :

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell: NFXRippleCell = NFXRippleCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        cell.textLabel?.text = aSport[indexPath.row].name
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 16)
        cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()

        return cell
}
```

and my `prepareForSegue` :

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        let cell = sender as! NFXRippleCellN
        let row = tableView.indexPathForCell(cell)?.row
        let detail = segue.destinationViewController as! SecondTableViewController
        detail.selectedSport = aSport[row!]
    }
```

What should I adjust? or is there something I am missing?

UPDATE: HERE IS HE CODE IN MY CONTROLLER:

```
   override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell: NFXRippleCell = NFXRippleCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        cell.textLabel?.text = aSportl[indexPath.row].name
        cell.textLabel?.text = aSport[indexPath.row].name
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Thin", size: 16)
        cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) { performSegueWithIdentifier("firstSports", sender: self.tableView(tableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath) ) }


    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        let cell = sender as! NFXRippleCell
        let row = tableView.indexPathForCell(cell)?.row
        let detail = segue.destinationViewController as! SecondTableViewController
        detail.selectedSchool = aSport[row!]
    }
```

Comment: This may be a dumb question but does the segue exist? Is `prepareForSegue` ever being called?

Comment: huh? i don't understand @dmarsi

Comment: In your `prepareForSegue` function you cast sender in `NFXRippleCellN`, is it normal ?

Comment: oh no that was just a typo while copy and pasting on here @Mindsers

Comment: @MikeStrong Did you create the segue in your storyboard? If you put a breakpoint in `prepareForSegue` is it getting hit when you select a cell?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to call segue programmatically ? Maybe the solution is just to use `tableView(_: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath: NSIndexPath)` to call your segue.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) 
{ 
    performSegueWithIdentifier("first", sender: self.tableView(tableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath) ) 
}
```

Comment: what code should go within that method to prepare a segue?

Comment: Not *prepare* but *perform*. Try `performSegueWithIdentifier()`. This method will call the segue and your `prepareforSegue` method

Comment: used the following : `override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        performSegueWithIdentifier("first", sender: NFXRippleCell())
    }`

Comment: @MikeStrong try to change `NFXRippleCell()` for `self.tableView(tableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)`

Comment: change it exactly where ?

Comment: @MikeStrong try the following : `override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {        performSegueWithIdentifier("first", sender: self.tableView(tableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath) )    }`

Comment: i can't use that type of segue or else it will break my data passing from my tablee views, theres a reason i have that code within my prepare for segue method

Comment: is it normal for these subviews to interfere with segues?

Comment: I don't understand : `performSegueWithIdentifier` should call your `prepareForSegue` method. So this shouldn't break your data..

Comment: maybe I am missing something, `performSegueWithIdentifier` can call `prepareForSegue`? how? I mean because every string in my prepareForSegue is vital.. thats all Im saying

Comment: prepareForSegue(_:sender:)
"Called when a segue is about to be performed."

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSSeguePerforming_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSSeguePerforming/

Comment: what I'm saying is how exactly should the code look to include my prepareForSegue, because when I simply implemented  `: override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) { performSegueWithIdentifier("first", sender: NFXRippleCell()) }` my data was screwed up

Comment: It's because you didn't give a real sender to `performSegueWithIdentifier`. Try to give it the cell tapped by user.

When you give it `NFXRippleCell()` you just give it an instance of cell who isn't in your tableView.

Comment: check out my updated question to see what my code looks like now